# Request headers in redirection

Tags: http, request, http-headers, httprequest

My application has some internal redites where it checks for authentication. So i ma trying to understand here about request headers.

Say my application redirects from A--> B-->C. So can i access the request headers from A while in C?

Please clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot access page A headers in page C directly. What you can do,

1. Store the required headers of Page A in server, then access it in page C by accessing server.
2. Redirect by adding required header to B, then add the required header to C.
3. Change the flow such a way, where A and C are not linked by the headers.